# How to split string with trailing empty strings in result?

Tags: scala

I am a bit confused about Scala string split behaviour as it does not work consistently and some list elements are missing. For example, if I have a CSV string with 4 columns and 1 missing element.

```
"elem1, elem2,,elem 4".split(",") = List("elem1", "elem2", "", "elem4")
```

Great! That's what I would expect.

On the other hand, if both element 3 and 4 are missing then:

```
"elem1, elem2,,".split(",") = List("elem1", "elem2")
```

Whereas I would expect it to return

```
"elem1, elem2,,".split(",") = List("elem1", "elem2", "", "")
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As Peter mentioned in his answer, `"string".split()`, in both Java and Scala, does not return trailing empty strings by default.

You can, however, specify for it to return trailing empty strings by passing in a second parameter, like this:

```
String s = "elem1,elem2,,";
String[] tokens = s.split(",", -1);
```

And that will get you the expected result.

You can find the related [Java doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Answer (score 4):

I believe that trailing empty spaces are not included in a return value.

JavaDoc for `split(String regex)` says: "This method works as if by invoking the two-argument `split` method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."

So in your case `split(String regex, int limit)` should be used in order to get trailing empty string in a return value.