# scala split double pipe(||) not printing last columns if null

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split

I need to write a Spark Scala code to split string. My delimiter is double pipe (||). The split gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the last field is null. Can someone please help me to solve this issue. This issue is happening only if the last field is null. Here is my code :

```
val str1 = "one||two||three||"
val splitfields1 = str1.split("\\|\\|")
println(splitfields1(2))

//output : three

val str2 = "one||||three||"
val splitfields2 = str2.split("\\|\\|")
println(splitfields2(2))
println(splitfields2(1))
// output1 : three
// output2 : Empty line

val str3 = "one||two||||"
val splitfields3 = str3.split("\\|\\|")
println(splitfields3(2))
// Error : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
// I expected field number 2 will have null/empty string and wont give outofbound exception

splitfields3.foreach { println }
//Output : one
           two
//Here it is not printing empty line
```

How to solve this. I am taking inputs from a file, so it can have null fields in any position.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689065/how-to-split-string-with-trailing-empty-strings-in-result

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
val splitfields3 = str3.split("\\|\\|",-1)
```

Comment: You might want to add some text explaining what is the extra parameter `-1` used for.

Comment: You better explain your solution than just posting some anonymous code section. You should read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers).

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to format the code in mobile. About the meaning of -1, I think the asker can refer the API doc.